# BPM is always null recently in SoundCloud api

Tags: soundcloud

I'm developing an app that relies on the bpm parameter, which I'm getting from querying SoundCloud API.
Recently the API always returns null value for the bpm, with the same queries that is used to return a real value.
This is an example of one of the queries I've tried (from SoundCloud HTTP API console https://developers.soundcloud.com/console) :

https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?consumer_key=apigee&filter=all&order=created_at&bpm-from=120&bpm-to=220&order=original

Is there a way for not getting null values for bpm or filter the results that contains null?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They've changed their [API](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference). The correct URL in your case should be:

https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?consumer_key=apigee&filter=all&order=created_at&bpm[from]=120&bpm[to]=220&order=original

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it and it worked for some of the tracks. Than I change it into https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?consumer_key=apigee&filter=all&order=created_at&bpm[from]=120&bpm[to]=220&order=original and it works like a charm!

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to update the 'from' part. Updated the answer. Glad to hear that you got it working!